# Do I have unallocated space of 15G or higher?

Tags: 18.04, windows-10

This is my 1st time installing Ubuntu on my windows machine. I am following this guide to install Ubuntu 18.04: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot.html. In step 2, it says "**If your system already has unallocated space (at least 15GB or 20GB) then you can skip this step and go directly to Installation of Ubuntu 18.04.**"
So here is my screenshot of partitions:
[image]

I have highlighted 2 partitions each of which has more than 15G, but I think these 2 are not unallocated (because they are highlighted in blue color, not in black, as shown in the picture), so should I skip shrinking or should I shrink a partition? If I must shrink one of them, which one should I shrink?

Comment: Your system does not have any unallocated space on the hard drive. "Windows (C:)" is your main Windows partition. Deleting that will cause Windows to stop working. "LENOVO_PART" has 11GB of data recorded on it, so this is probably a recovery partition that is used if you want to re-install Windows. You will need to shrink "C:" by 25 GB, then use that space for Ubuntu. Alternatively, if this is "just a test", perhaps running off the Live USB or installing in a VM would be a safer path for now.

Comment: Please note the official minimum requirement for Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 & later (including Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) is 25GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)   Yes many 3rd party blogs say you can use less space, and yes you can, but you need to be careful with how you use it, limit yourself to certain apps & avoiding installing a lot of applications etc, plus plan to *nuke & install* rather than *release-upgrade* (ie. start again instead of upgrade as intended; as the upgrade requires extra space - hence 25GB minimum)

Comment: You can probably make some space, but do not think you will be happy for long.  Think you might be happier with an external drive to place Ubuntu on, it will work just as well and will give you extra space that I don't think you can really afford on your Windows drive.  15 or 25GBs most people will find quite tiny and want more space soon.  It can be done, but why have headaches after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your space is allocated.  Most of it is in the Windows partition. You should try to shrink that one.  The other one you've highlighted is a Lenovo provided rescue partition to aid with Windows system recovery issues. Don't touch that one. You might need it one day.

Comment: His Windows is at 83% full now, doubt reducing it in his best interest, without Windows giving headaches because of not enough space.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you reading the partition maps, it shows that the Windows partition is 83 % FREE not 83 % Used, with careful but not greedy partitioning, there will be ample room to install Ubuntu partitions.  I recommend one for root (/), tmp (/tmp), var (/var), and (/opt),  plus a separate partition for home (/home) where the user's files will reside.